# OOTB refiner with And condition

Tags: search-results, refiner

Is it possible to configure a refiner to refine based on a value in a column and a content type.

Our search results page has multiple content types.

All content types have the column A e.g.

We want a refiner to display all values from a content type and where value of col A = x

Comment: Are you trying to use single refiner to refine Content Type as well as column value?

Comment: @ThinkB4Code yes that is what I am hoping to do

Comment: There is no OOB solution available for this kind of functionality. Alternatively, you can use Search Box to do similar kind of job. If you type free text in search box, get any content which has the keyword or if it matches the ContentType or Refiner Column value.

Comment: Otherwise you need to use custom build solution to support such functionality.

Comment: Thanks. ThinkB4Code